# CQL IN set query

Tags: cassandra, cql

Have a table

```
REATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabletest (uuid text, uuidHotel text, uuidRoom text, uuidGuest text, bookedTimeStampSet set<text>, PRIMARY KEY (uuidHotel, uuidRoom));
```

Tried to select with IN:

```
select * from tabletest where uuidhotel = 'uuidHotel' and bookedtimestampset IN ('1460710800000');
```

Got

```
'bookedtimestampset' (set<text>) cannot be restricted by a 'IN' relation"
```

Can I select elements by IN Set filter?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I select elements by IN Set filter?

No, but you can put a secondary index on `bookedtimestampset` and use the `CONTAINS` operator:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> CREATE INDEX timeset_idx ON tabletest(bookedtimestampset);

aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT uuidhotel,uuidroom FROM tabletest 
  WHERE uuidhotel = 'uuidHotel1' and bookedtimestampset CONTAINS '1460710800000';

  uuidhotel | uuidroom
------------+----------
 uuidHotel1 | uuidroom1

(1 rows)
```

Normally I wouldn't recommend a secondary index, but as long as you are filtering by a partition key (`uuidhotel`) it should perform ok.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I select elements by IN Set filter?

you can't use clause **IN** with your primary key. It is highly important to understand how significantly data model influences on query performance. Of course, you can add secondary index for column *bookedtimestampset* but in this case be ready to for performance degradation.

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabletest (uuid text, uuidHotel text, uuidRoom text, uuidGuest text, bookedTimeStampSet set, PRIMARY KEY (uuidHotel, uuidRoom));

your compound primary key consists of one partition key **uuidHotel** and one clustering key **uuidRoom** which means that all your hotels and rooms would physically stored on same node in order as result retrieval of rows is very efficient. **bookedTimeStampSet** is different column which would be spread through whole cluster and it is just impossible to restrict by this column without secondary indexing one.

Consequently. I would recommend you to create primary key according to your future queries even if you need to duplicate some data which is common practice for NoSql database such Cassandra is.

e.q.

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabletest (uuid text, uuidHotel text,
>   uuidRoom text, uuidGuest text, bookedTimeStamp timestamp, PRIMARY KEY
>   (uuidHotel, bookedTimeStamp , uuidRoom))

it allows you to make a query like

> select * from tabletest where uuidhotel = 'uuidHotel' and
>   bookedtimestamp > '1460710800000 and bookedtimestamp < '1460710900000'